# Cannot properly connect gitlab server and gitlab runnner

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to connect gitlab container and gitlab runner container to execute jobs. But i get error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'http://<gitlab-server-container-ip-address>/test/test-project.git/': Failed to connect to <gitlab-server-container-ip-address> port 80 after 130331 ms: Couldn't connect to server
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

So, first I start gitlab:

```
docker run --detach   --hostname <gitlab-server-container-ip-address>  --publish 80:80 --publish 2222:22 -p 8443:443 -p 9419:9419 --name gitlab --restart always   --volume $GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab   --volume $GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab   --volume $GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab --network=gitlab-network   --shm-size 256m   gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest
```

Then, runner:

```
docker run --name gitlab-runner --restart always -p 8080:80 -p 443:443 -p 2200:22 -p 8093:8093 -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner   -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --network=gitlab-network  gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

Aslo, I set `url = "http://<gitlab-server-container-ip-address>/"` in `config.toml` file of runner.

Any idea why this happening?

A try to change port mapping but always is the same result.

Comment: Solved: Need to add

external_url = "http://<ip:port_of_gitlab_server>/"

and name of network where are server and runner

network_mode = "gitlab_network_name"

in config.toml file of gitlab runner under [runners.docker].